# Batch create folders from files with similar beginning but different ending

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a lof of files with similar beginning names, but ending different. I have to create a folder for every "series" of files, which means all files whose names begin with the same 7 characers.

See image for visualization:
[image]

The code I have right now is
`for /F "Tokens=*" %%i in ('Dir /B *.jpg') do md "%%~ni"|copy "%%i" "%%~ni"`
Which just creates a folder for every file and puts it inside.

Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of this language and just googling it only made me learn how to create a substring `SET _result=%_test:~0,7%` but not how to create folders with that.

I'm sure it's just a short sequence, could someone help me with that?

Comment: `|` constitutes a pipe, meaning that the output of a command is passed to the input of another one; I assume you simply want to execute multiple commands, so use `&`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way of doing this, but it should help you. The below batch script takes an input folder and output folder as inputs from user. It then iterates through all the files in the input folder and copies them to output folder under a sub-folder with first 7 characters of the filename.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Get input directory from user
set /p INPUT_DIR=Please enter full path to directory with files:
REM Get ouput directory from user
set /p OUTPUT_DIR=Please enter full path to output directory:
REM Iterate through files and create necessary folders/copy files
for /f %%f in ('dir /b %INPUT_DIR%') do (
    set fullname=%%f
    set trimmedname=!fullname:~0,7!
    set fullpath=%OUTPUT_DIR%\!trimmedname!
    if not exist !fullpath! md !fullpath!
    copy %INPUT_DIR%\%%f !fullpath!
)
```

Here's a sample output that shows the processing done by the script:

[image: Ouptut]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this, it works. I have another issue though: The name lengths now aren't just 7 anymore, but can vary in length. So I have stuff like 01234_x and 012345_y or something wihout an undescore, like 01234.
This shouldn't be very hard, I just need an IF that checks if the name contains an underscore and if yes, make a substring from the first half. If it doesn't contain an underscore it should just take the full name. But holy sh*t is batch programming complicated, I only managed to make the IF work, the ELSE throws an error for some reason. Could you help me a bit here?

Comment: Just replace `set trimmedname=!fullname:~0,7!` in my answer with `for /f "tokens=1 delims=_." %%s in ('echo !fullname!') do set trimmedname=%%s` and see if it helps. This command will split the string with either **_** or **.** (to remove extension) and use the first token as the folder name.